# Interpolation across planar narrow-band level sets in OpenVDB

Tags: c++, 3d, interpolation, spatial-interpolation, openvdb

I'm aware of OpenVDB's voxel value interpolation for sparse point clouds, but I'm still learning.

I have a triangle, and I find the narrow band level set of voxels it intersects. I assign the points in that level set to a point group and assign values to a few points within that level set.

Lets say that I then wanted to interpolate values for other points in that level set. Would I have to extract the points into a separate Grid first, or is there some kind of operation that could interpolate only across the points in that level set group?

My primary reason for asking is because I maintain several Grids already for different properties of the points, and it seems excessive to create a separate Grid object for each triangular face.